# Android Toolbar doesn't hide a title

Tags: android, android-actionbar-compat

I can't hide a title in my `Toolbar` that I set as `ActionBar`.
Here my activity style:

```
<style name="Theme.Paper" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
</style>
```

Layout:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>
        <!-- some data -->
    </data>

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Paper.AppBarOverlay">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
                layout="@layout/toolbar_spinner"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</layout>
```

And `Toolbar` layout:

```
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.Paper.Toolbar.PopupOverlay"
        app:theme="@style/Theme.Paper.Spinner.PopupOverlay">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_spinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.Paper.Spinner.PopupOverlay"/>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</layout>
```

Here a code is in the `onCreate` method:

```
mBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_editor);
//Set ToolBar
setSupportActionBar(mBinding.toolbarLayout.toolbar);
//Up navigation
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

if (actionBar != null) {
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false); // Try to hide a title
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(VectorDrawable
       .getDrawable(this, R.drawable.ic_close_white_24dp));
}
```

But it doesn't work, a title still shows.
Where can a problem be?

**ADDED**
This is my debug screen:
[image: Screenshot]
As you can see my `ActionBar` is not null.

Comment: I think you shouldn't create ActionBar and assign it as a `getSupportActionBar();` just call `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);` that works for me every time.

Comment: It's equal. But I already checked this version too. It doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

As you are using toolbar you can use:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
```

Comment: Thanks! I know that I can just set an empty text. But I wanna get why a normal variant doesn't work.

Comment: you are using theme `NoActionBar`  so your `ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar()`;...will give null

Comment: Guy, I set a `Toolbar` like an `ActionBar`, it's not null. As argument, my program works perfect.

Comment: okay ..but if `actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false)`  this line executes it is supposed to remove the title

Comment: I think all same but it doesn't work. And it's my question: why? (I updated my thread to you can sure that my `ActionBar` is not null)

Comment: do you have <activity  android:label="@string/title_activity_name" >  inside your AndroidManifest.xml file, if it is then remove the android:label="@string/title_activity_name" and the title will no longer show on the Toolbar.